# ​ How to pass Swift object to C++ method in direct interop

Tags: c++, swift

I have following issue:
I'm experimenting with direct C++ <=> Swift direct interop inside one framework (https://www.swift.org/documentation/cxx-interop), based on this example: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mixinglanguagesinanxcodeproject

I've created swift class in Fibonacci framework, that is intended to be used from C++ code

```
public class SwiftSideInterfaceBridge
{
    public func Callback() -> String
    {
        return "Some string"
    }
}
```

Then I need C++ class, that will accept object of previous swift class in one of the methods

```
class CxxToSwiftInterfaceBridge
{
public:
    std::string Call();
    void RegisterCallback( Fibonacci::SwiftSideInterfaceBridge bridge );
    static CxxToSwiftInterfaceBridge& Instance();
};
```

But I have a problem
If I try to include swift-generated header in my hpp file - I'm getting error that this file doesn't exist

```
#include <Fibonacci/Fibonacci-Swift.h> //file not found

class CxxToSwiftInterfaceBridge
{
// as previous
};
```

If I try to forward-declare my SwiftSideInterfaceBridge in hpp and include swift header in cpp file, this function isn't imported in swift

```
namespace Fibonacci
{
class SwiftSideInterfaceBridge;
}

class CxxToSwiftInterfaceBridge
{
public:
   std::string Call(); // This function is available in swift
   void RegisterCallback( Fibonacci::SwiftSideInterfaceBridge bridge ); // This function is not available in swift
};
```

Is there a way to mark forward-declared class as swift-side, so this function will be correctly imported in Swift?